# How to convert .OBJ to .CGNS

Tags: linux, windows, 3d, 3d-modeling

Working with 3d geometry. I need to convert .OBJ file obtained from maya/3ds max to .CGNS (a really strange format described [here](http://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/cgns/CGNS_docs_current/user/started.html)). Is there an application that can do this (for windows or ubuntu?)